# AvAudioRecorder settings configuration help

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, avaudiorecorder

I want to record a .caf file then send it as a mail attachment and pick it up on my mac. The problem is the caf file is not playable outside my app, only in my app. What setting do i have to use to play the .caf file whit Quicktime on my mac here are my setting. I save the audio file in the iphone Documents directory.

```
 NSDictionary *settings =[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleLossless],    AVFormatIDKey,
                            [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 44100.0],                 AVSampleRateKey,
                            [NSNumber numberWithInt: 2],                         AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                            [NSNumber numberWithInt:128000],                     AVEncoderBitRateKey,
                            [NSNumber numberWithInt: AVAudioQualityMax],         AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
                          nil];
```

I am using a external platform to send the attachment, i am sending it to a web server converted in base

```
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
    NSString *filePath2 = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"VoiceMail.caf"];
    attachment1.FileData = [serv convertFileToB64String:filePath2 fileName:@"VoiceMail.caf"];
    attachment1.FileName = @"VoiceMail.caf";
    message.Attachments = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:attachment1, nil];
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this setting, this should work.

```
   NSMutableDictionary* recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatLinearPCM] forKey:AVFormatIDKey]; 
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:9500.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey]; 
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityHigh] forKey:AVEncoderAudioQualityKey];
    [recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithInt:16] forKey:AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey];
    [recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey];
    [recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey];
```

Comment: I tried the settings it still does not play outside my application

Comment: i need to see the code for how do you attach this .caf file to mail attachment.

Comment: I am using an outside platform to send the e-mail attachment, i will put the code in a few seconds,

Comment: i might have found the error,to send the message to my web service,i transform it in base64 and i thing that might be the problem, i used the base64 library on other objects and worked perfecly, i  will try it again see what is wrong.

Comment: the problem was with the base64 conversion, it had a bug in the buffers and did not convert it as it should.